# Discord.js v13 [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
    const key = `${message.guild.id}|${message.channel.id}|${message.id}`;

    if (MESSAGE_CACHE.has(key)) {
      const cachedMessage = MESSAGE_CACHE.get(key);
      const logChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(settings.log_channel);
      if (!logChannel) return;

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Ghost ping detected")
        .setDescription(
          `**Message**:
        ${cachedMessage.content}
        
        **Author:** ${cachedMessage.author.tag} \`${cachedMessage.author.id}\`
        **Channel:** <#${cachedMessage.channelId}>
        `
        )
        .addField("Members", cachedMessage.mentions.members, true)
        .addField("Roles", cachedMessage.mentions.roles, true)
        .addField("Everyone?", cachedMessage.mentions.everyone, true)
        .setFooter("Sent at: " + cachedMessage.createdAt);

      sendMessage(logChannel, { embeds: [embed] });
    }
```

If i delete a message with a ghost ping in it, it returns the error
`Unhandled Rejection at: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.`
Any idea why this happeneds as the fields have valures

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On `.addField` creating the error, to prevent this errors,

```
.addField("Members", `${cachedMessage.mentions.members || "Your word"}`, true)
.addField("Roles", `${cachedMessage.mentions.roles || "Your word"}`, true)
.addField("Everyone?", `${cachedMessage.mentions.everyone || "Your word"}`, true)
.setFooter("Sent at: " + cachedMessage.createdAt);
```

**explanation:** if your bot didn't get any members that pinged someone, instead of throwing an error, it will send a `string`

Comment: Even there is a mentioned member in the message, discord.js still throws the error because `cachedMessage.mentions.members` is a collection not a string.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As ACGaming mentioned, none of those will work as `members`, `roles`, etc are not strings.

Answer (score 1):

All the values you put there are not strings, so it will throw that error. Also, note that `.mentions.members` and `.mentions.roles` are `Collection`s, not arrays, so you need to convert them.

```js
.addField("Members", `${Array.from(cachedMessage.mentions.members.values()).join(", ") || "None"}`, true)
.addField("Roles", `${Array.from(cachedMessage.mentions.roles.values()).join(", ") || "None"}`, true)
.addField("Everyone?", `${cachedMessage.mentions.everyone}`, true)
.setFooter("Sent at: " + `${cachedMessage.createdAt}`);
```